# How would I convert from POS to SOP?

Tags: design

[image]

Hey guys I need a clear explanation on how I would go about converting from POS to SOP form.

Comment: Im mainly confused about the outlier w, What would you do if that is there?

Comment: Draw a truth table. You know how to extract SOP or POS from it, don't you?

Comment: or else should I add. How can I construct the karnograph map with the equation to then get the SOP form that way?

Comment: @JordanSole, you don't use a Karnaugh map to get a SOP (or POS) equation. You use it to get a simpler equation than the SOP or POS equation.

Comment: Jordan < I am surprised you could not search for a solution  https://www.electronicshub.org/boolean-logic-sop-form-pos-form/#Conversion_of_POS_form_to_SOP_form

Comment: I dont know exactly know how to draw a truth table from this. The w is the only thing throwing me off.

Comment: @JordanSole, \$w\$ is a sum with only one term.

Comment: @ThePhoton So does that mean on the KMAP it would cover 8 slots?

Comment: @JordanSole, show us why you think it's 8 slots?

Comment: @ThePhoton 8 slots because w would be 0, and that would be for 8 different slots.

Comment: And there's no way to get a 0 with \$w=1\$?

Comment: @ThePhoton Well then wouldn't w have 8 slots with a 1 then?

Comment: Go back to Eugene's comment. Step 1 is write out the truth table.

Comment: This is the **fundamental de Morgan's Law**   labelled as  POS <==> SOP conversion.  You may expect to transform  as many times as there are inputs (4) or use a KMAP to achieve the desired end result

Comment: Why is everyone so negative, I don't understand lol maybe I was not the clearest, but jeezzzzz. I am trying to learn the absolute basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you have POS, product of sums. The product is of three terms (x+y'+z) (x'+y+z) and w. The first two terms are sums. That is why this notation is called product of sums.

You need SOP, sum of products.

Multiply them out. The first few terms will be xx'w + xyw + ..., you can do the rest. These terms are products, and they are all added together, or summed. When you've multiplied everything out, you will be left with a sum of products, or SOP. If you have any terms that are identical apart from a scaling factor, group them together before submitting your final answer.